# How do i verify the call to mocked instance when the instance takes "this" as parameter

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit

I have a method which has call to event publisher, i want to verify the call to this publisher.

```
public void submitRegistrationForm(String registrationKey, RegistrationFormSubmitDTO registrationFormSubmitDTO) {
applicationEventPublisher.publishEvent(new RegistrationCompletedEvent(this, targetCustomerRegistration));
  }
```

So, i mocked the applicationEventPublisher class and i had verified the call to it like this:

```
verify(applicationEventPublisher, times(1)).publishEvent(any(RegistrationCompletedEvent.class));
```

but i was told not to use any(), instead i need to build the concrete instance.
how can i verify the method which takes "this" as parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an argument captor to capture the RegistrationCompletedEvent and assert on it...

```
ArgumentCaptor<RegistrationCompletedEvent > argument = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(RegistrationCompletedEvent .class);
verify(applicationEventPublisher).publishEvent(argument.capture());
assertEquals("whatever", argument.getValue().something());
```